# How to cite literary (fiction) fragments in a naturals sciences journal?

Tags: fiction, citations

I'm writing a grant in psychology/cognitive neuroscience. I am considering including a fragment of a book at the beginning, to illustrate the question. Regardless of whether this is a good idea, is there any special way to reference fragments of a novel in an otherwise scientific journal? My memory from reading this in journals is that the name of the autor is explicitly written next to the passage, even if the citation style includes only numbers within the text.

I couldn't find this in the APA manual, though I might have easily missed it.

Comment: When you say APA, do you mean American Psychological (or Psychiatric) Association or a misprint of AP style guide? Either way, my response would be to pick a style guide (such as AP or THE CHICAGO MANUAL OF STYLE) and follow their lead. If that still gets you nowhere, try to find an example you like and go with it.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't that be considered a citation just like any other? There shouldn't be a distinction between the 'genre' of work. The basic purpose of citations is to ensure appropriate representation of your own original thoughts and words vs the work of others.

APA: Single Author 
https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/06/

APA: Books
https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/08/